# telethon error when getting a link to a folder

Tags: python, telethon

I do everything according to the documentation, here is the link https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/chatlists/export_chatlist_invite.html
and here is my code:

```
    result = client(functions.chatlists.ExportChatlistInviteRequest(
        chatlist=types.InputChatlistDialogFilter(
            filter_id=42
        ),
        title='lol',
        peers=include_peers
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

there is one public channel and one public chat in the folder, but for some reason it gives an error telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FilterNotSupportedError: The specified filter cannot be used in this context (caused by ExportChatlistInviteRequest)

in the include_peers, those chats that are in the folder, I added them using telethon and then I tried get the link

I tried to change different filters and asked gpt, there are no results, but this particular filter is in the documentation

Comment: tl.telethon.dev is autogenerated. they're not "docs", just scheme. replace 42 with an actual folder id after you create it with UpdateDialogFilters. and check the Telegram documentation on [chatlists](https://core.telegram.org/api/folders#shared-folders) and [filters/folders](https://core.telegram.org/api/folders#folders) for creation and getting